# Animate widget to it's default size

Tags: flutter

I have a ListTile widget that I would like to grow into existence when added by the user. The issue is that I can't find a way to detect the tile's height so that I can provide that as the end of a tween for the tile's size. `context.size.height` works great, but I have to display a single frame first, then start the animation with `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);`. However, the widget flashes at full size (moving other tiles) for a frame, before the animation starts. How can I see what height I should animate to before the widget is displayed? Thanks for your answers!
[image]

[code here](https://pastebin.com/bNyCPnt7)

Comment: could you add some code to test?

Comment: @diegoveloper Added link in post

Comment: you can use ExpansionPanel, here you have an example: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/expansion_panels_demo.dart

Comment: That animates nested widgets, I want it to animate the tile itself. I use the ExpansionTile for the checked tasks and that works fine

Comment: Did you found a solution?